# Use the command bar in bash without I/O?

Tags: bash, programming

I really like the look of the output of [`bar`](http://www.theiling.de/projects/bar.html)

But that script is only used for Input/Output operations.

How can I use it as a replacement for sleep but with visual feedback?

```
sleep 10
```

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't see a way to do this using `bar`. However you might be interested in these other commands that do the same thing, that might suite your needs better.

#### Method #1 - Fake it

This method will simply overwrite what's been previously displayed to the screen with a larger progress bar. Simple but effective.

Example, `ex.bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -ne '#####                     (33%)\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne '#############             (66%)\r'
sleep 1
echo -ne '#######################   (100%)\r'
echo -ne '\n'
```

#### Method #2 - pipeview

The command `pv` provides progress bar functionality. You can see more elaborate examples in this article titled: [A Unix Utility You Should Know About: Pipe Viewer](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/unix-utilities-pipe-viewer/).

```
$ pv access.log | gzip > access.log.gz
611MB 0:00:11 [58.3MB/s] [=>      ] 15% ETA 0:00:59
```

#### Method #3 - spinner

You can use the following sample code to construct your own "spinner" using a simple loop. Within the loop you could embed whatever commands you like. This code comes from this article, titled: [Can I do a spinner in Bash?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/034).

```
#!/bin/bash

sp='/-\|'
printf ' '
for i in $(seq 3); do
  printf '\b%.1s' "$sp"
  sp=${sp#?}${sp%???}
  sleep 1
done
echo ''
```

#### Method #4 - dialog

There's a command called `dialog` which does pretty much what you want. It makes use of graphical dialogs, but they're ncurses based so they'll work in most every terminal and/or script so long as there's support for ncurses. You can see all the [`dialog` documentation on the project's website](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html).

*screenshot*

[image: ss of guage]

#### References

- [How to add a progress bar to a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238073/how-to-add-a-progress-bar-to-a-shell-script)

Comment: About [slm](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7453/slm)'s the method #1, a more complete example: **[progressbar.sh](https://github.com/haikieu/shell-progressbar/blob/master/progressbar.sh)**.

Answer (score 0):

It seems trivial to implement. The bash function below (bar) below behaves like your `bar` script (based on the short screencast). It also resizes dynamically with the terminal width (on the next call to `bar`).

```
#!/bin/bash

#Helper functions
terminal_width(){
  local width_height=`stty size`
  echo ${width_height/* /}
}
string_times_n(){
  local s=$1
  local n=$2
  for((i=0;i<n; i++)); do echo -n "$s"; done
}
##The actual function
bar(){
  local percentage=$1
  local padding=10
  local width=$(echo "scale=0; 0.5 * $(terminal_width)" | bc | cut -d. -f1)
  local equals_n=$(echo "$percentage * $width / 100" | bc | cut -d. -f1)
  local dots_n=$((width - equals_n))

  #ANSI escape sequence magic
  local Esc="\033["
  local up="$Esc""K""$Esc""1A""$Esc""K"

  #Clear the line
  string_times_n ' ' "$width"
  echo -ne "\r"

  #Print the current screen
  printf  "%3s%% [" "$percentage"
    string_times_n '=' "$equals_n"
    string_times_n '.' "$dots_n"
  echo -n "]"

  #Go up unless finished
  if [[ "$percentage" == 100 ]] 
  then
    echo
  else
    echo -e "$up"
  fi
}
```

#### Usage

```
. bar.sh #Assuming it's saved in bar.sh
bar $percentage
```

#### Regular progress example:

```
for i in {1..10}; do bar $((i*10)); sleep 0.1; done;
```

#### Random progress example:

```
for i in {1..10}; do bar $((i*10)); sleep `echo $RANDOM / 10000|bc`; done;
```